# How to use $ref in swagger file properly while working with swagger-ui-express and swagger-jsdoc

Tags: node.js, json, express, swagger, ref

I started to use swagger with **swagger-ui-express** and **swagger-jsdoc** to auto document my existing API, which is written with *nodejs* and express (like described here - [example](http://www.acuriousanimal.com/2018/10/20/express-swagger-doc.html)).

I came across a problem when I tried to add a `$ref` to an existing *JSON Schema* file (that sits inside my project on the same directory as all my js files) on my annotation.

[My directory looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPON2.png)

I tried to write the local path (`./schema.json`) and the absolute path, tried to use `#`, using many syntaxes and nothing worked.

My annotation looks like this:

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * /testing:
 *    get:
 *      description: This should show the json schema
 *      responses:
 *          200:
 *              description: "successful operation"
 *              schema:
 *                 $ref: "./schema.json"
 */
```

I expected the swagger ui to show me the JSON schema in my request section by. I get the following error -

```
Resolver error at paths./testing.get.responses.200.schema.$ref
Could not resolve reference: Tried to resolve a relative URL, without having a basePath. path: './schema.json' basePath: 'undefined'.
```

I looked the problem up online and couldn’t find any clear answer. I saw a solution that suggested I should put my schema on a server and access it with an URL address but I prefer not to do it on this point.

Also, at some point, I saved the scheme in a variable and then put it in the `$ref` and it worked fine. The only problem was that the scheme included some inner refs to an element in the same file and *Swagger* couldn't resolve them.

Is there a way to work properly with `$ref` in **swagger-ui-express**?

Comment: there ist an open ticket on github:
https://github.com/arjun-g/vs-swagger-viewer/issues/45

Comment: Sadly, issues concerning paths inside `$ref` plague nearly each Swagger/OpenAPI tool. Vote for fixing them or post a PR at Github.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to work properly with $ref in swagger-ui-express?

Yes, there is, you have to resolve references in your YAML files by your self first, and provide result to Swagger UI then. You can do it with [json-refs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-refs) and [yamljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yamljs) libraries.

Here is the code snippet below shows you how you can do it:

```js
const yamljs = require('yamljs');
const { resolveRefs } = require('json-refs');

/**
 * Return JSON with resolved references
 * @param {array | object} root - The structure to find JSON References within (Swagger spec)
 * @returns {Promise.<JSON>}
 */
const multiFileSwagger = (root) => {
  const options = {
    filter: ["relative", "remote"],
    loaderOptions: {
      processContent: function (res, callback) {
        callback(null, yamljs.parse(res.text));
      },
    },
  };

  return resolveRefs(root, options).then(
    function (results) {
      return results.resolved;
    },
    function (err) {
      console.log(err.stack);
    }
  );
};


const swaggerDocument = await multiFileSwagger(
  yamljs.load(path.resolve(__dirname, "./openapi/v1.yaml"))
);
```

You can also check the repo with full example how this solution works with swagger-ui-express: https://github.com/chuve/swagger-multi-file-spec

Comment: If you are executing this function not in the same path of the YAML file, consider to add `location: <your full yaml file path>` to the options. Ref: https://github.com/whitlockjc/json-refs/blob/master/docs/API.md#module_json-refs.JsonRefsOptions

Answer (score 1):

got the same problem here and find your question.

I've just solved mine so I guess I might help.

First, have you tried:

```
schema:
      $ref: "schema.json"
```

without the `.` This is how they teach at the documentation.