# When documenting with swagger-ui-express and swagger-jsdoc, how to point to json file for schema definition?

Tags: swagger

I am currently using ajv to validate some API inputs in node/express. The expected data is described in a .json schema file.

Now I would like to re-use this file to document my API, relying on swagger-ui-express and swagger-jsdoc.

There are quite many references to how to re-use an object definition in swagger, but all these descriptions suppose that definition is given in a "@swagger" comment block.

I simply don't see how to point to a local JSON file.

If my comment is shaped like this:

```
/**
* @swagger
* /init/user:
*   post:
*     description: Creates a user
*     produces:
*       - application/json
*     parameters:
*       - in: body
*         name: create user
*         required: true
*         schema:
*           $ref: 'schemas/initUserApi.json'
*/
```

(note this is an incomplete template, I want to focus on the problem), then the ultimate swagger output will throw an error:

`Could not resolve reference: Tried to resolve a relative URL, without having a basePath. path: 'schemas/initUserApi.json' basePath: 'undefined'`

I tried defining a 'components' section as described in this issue: [Cannot reference a component schema defined in a separate file in Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56632260/cannot-reference-a-component-schema-defined-in-a-separate-file-in-swagger), this does nothing.

I tried using absolute/relative file names, etc (also another suggestion here: [How to use $ref in swagger file properly while working with swagger-ui-express and swagger-jsdoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53968759/how-to-use-ref-in-swagger-file-properly-while-working-with-swagger-ui-express-a)), to no avail.

Is this possible? The goal is really to use a separate json file as a schema, as I would like to have a single source of information. I am not clear on how the swagger-ui-express/swagger-jsdoc chain works, would this json file need somehow to be served by my swagger web server (this is really for documentation running on localhost for now, no public/intranet publishing) ?

Comment: Did you solve this at the end? I am facing the same issue. Thank you in advance

Comment: No sorry, couldn't figure it out, I moved on to other things :-(

Answer (score 0):

it’s a bit old but for all those who are still looking for the solution it seems to me that this one works.

First, you have to **export** your schema from your json file as such:

```
export const initUserApi = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {...}
};
```

Then, in the file where your swagger configuration is located, you have to add this schema to your **Schemas**, inside your swagger **Components**:

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * infos: ...
 * basepath: ...
 * paths: ...
 * components:
 *   schemas:
 *     initUserApi:
 *       $ref: 'path/to/initUserApi.json'
 */
```

Once it’s done, you can use this new *initUserApi* schema with your routes as such:

```
/**
* @swagger
* /init/user:
*   post:
*     description: Creates a user
*     produces:
*       - application/json
*     parameters:
*       - in: body
*         name: create user
*         required: true
*         schema:
*           $ref: '#/components/schemas/initUserApi'
*/
```

But depending on your swagger/openapi version (2.0, 3.0.n, 3.1, etc...), this solution may not work, so you will probably have to convert your JSON file to YAML file. There is a bunch of online converters for this, the most easiest and most convenient being this one, which I often use: https://www.json2yaml.com/

Then it should normally work.